# google play apk expansion downloader library cause errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, importerror, apk-expansion-files

I've imported the project on my workspace (I did't copy it) recently and got 12 errors.
This application build target is android 2.3.3.
(minSdkVersion is "9" and maxSdkVersion is "14")
The problem is I have no idea with those sort of problems.
This application is in google playstore and all i want to do is just editing some codes but
i can't even build this project. I don't know the reason why. I'm not expert on this so please give me a help. 
How can i fix this?

Problems
12 errors, 25 warnings, 0 others

Errors (12 items)

```
error:Error:String types not allowed(at 'configChanges'with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize').
error:Error:String types not allowed(at 'configChanges'with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize').
NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD cannot be resolved or is not a field
NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP cannot be resolved or is not a field
NETWORK_TYPE_LTE cannot be resolved or is not a field
Notification.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
Notification.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library'/Users/Downloads/Folder/downloader_library/bin/downloader_library.jar'
The project cannot be built build path errors are resolved
TYPE_BLUETOOTH cannot be resolved or is not a field
Type_ETHERNET cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Answer (score 0):

The library is not found:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library'/Users/Downloads/Folder/downloader_library/bin/downloader_library.jar'
```

Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: one thing that i think mysterious is the 'downloader_library.jar' exists in right path like /Users/Downloads/Folder/downloader_library/bin/ when I import the project but the jar file disappear right away after the error is occurred like that. I mean, is library really matter in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever project have you imported, but within it, you missing one external library which is attached with that project, so you must need to include it first,because the reason of your errors are, some classes of that external library is used in your project, I think that is the only reason. Have you added that library or not?